# Extract string between period delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to extract **P4534** from the string below in SQL. The **length** between those two periods can change. So I need to account for longer strings between those two periods as well when doing a substring. How can I start at a different position?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><mydata>9.9.P4534.2.3</mydata>
```

Comment: Thanks but the value isn't always P4534. It can be something different and different lengths.

Answer (score 0):

The `AT()` function returns an integer indicating the position of the first character for a character expression.

```
STORE '9.9.P4534.2.3' TO gcString
STORE 'P4534' TO gcFindString
SUBSTRING(gcString, AT(gcFindString,gcString), 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl.  It's in XML, so you can utilize xQuery to get the value of `<mydata>`, then replace every '.' with `<M>` tags, then xQuery again to push that resultset into a table, and take row 3 as your value.

```
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(1000)
SET @STRING = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><mydata>9.9.P4534.2.3</mydata>'
--SET @STRING = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><mydata>9.9.P4456789534.2.3</mydata>'

DECLARE @XML TABLE (val VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT INTO @XML(val) SELECT @STRING

DECLARE @PARTS TABLE (id int identity(1,1), val VARCHAR(1000))

INSERT INTO @PARTS (val)
SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)') AS String
FROM  
(
    SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(CAST(Split.B.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)') AS VARCHAR), '.', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String
    FROM  (SELECT CAST(val AS XML) AS String  
           FROM @XML) AS B 
    CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/mydata') AS Split(B)
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)

SELECT val
FROM @PARTS
WHERE id=3
```